# How do I create a Multi-Index DB secondary index from a String?

Tags: smart-contract, multi-index, database, string

I'm developing a Smart Contract for EOSIO. I have a Multi-Index table with a `uint64_t` primary key. I'd like to add a secondary index to the table.

Ideally the data I'd be indexing on would be a `std::string`, but I'm under the impression that EOS does not allow that. I do see something in the [documentation](https://developers.eos.io/eosio-cpp/docs/db-api) referred to as an `idx256` described as a "256-bit fixed-size lexicographical key", though it is unclear how to construct one.

How do I create an `idx256`? What conversions must I do to a `std::string` to make it work (truncate or otherwise manipulate)? What are my limitations (for instance, is this a one-way conversion similar to hashing)? Any gotchas or other concerns I should be aware of?

Comment: I was going to say to use this https://developers.eos.io/eosio-cpp/reference#string_to_namebase32-str, but it's evidently deprecated: https://github.com/EOSIO/eosio.cdt/blob/6f14991bb514ec0b922778db5841deeca05c9d09/README.md#eosiolibtypeshpp

Comment: @Nat Do you suspect that it was deprecated in favor of the `""_n`/`name{""}` syntax? I mean...that might actually work for my purposes! I'm going to pursue this for a bit today and see if I can make it work for me

Comment: That could be the case.  If you look at this part of the tutorial, the usernames are coming back as plain text, so perhaps that could work for you as well. I couldn't figure out why though. https://developers.eos.io/eosio-home/docs/secondary-indices `"key": "alice"`

Answer (score 1):

As of `eosio.cdt v1.5.0`, you can not make a secondary index from a string.

The types of secondary indices allowed are:

```
    uint64_t    secondary_1;
    uint128_t   secondary_2;
    checksum256 secondary_3;
    double      secondary_4;
    long double secondary_5;
```

In principle, you could encode your string as a `eosio::name` and store it in a uint64_t, but this limits you to the 12 character-style names for eosio accounts.